# Check if float is "odd" or "even"?

Tags: python

If I have a number like `2122.6` I want to check if it is odd or even? I know this applies to integers generally. I will only print out one number after the decimal. I wish to just see if the last digit is odd or even.

Comment: Last integral digit or last digit?

Comment: Have you attempted to write any code to accomplish this?

Comment: last digit, as in the 6 in this case. I tried to use modulo with 0.2 but python was having none of it.

Comment: `str(my_float)[-1]` then just check that digit?

Comment: What if about `2.60000001`? Is that "odd" or "even"?

Comment: Thanks @cmd, was a rather silly question!

Comment: I think precision is going to bite you on this one.

Comment: @cmd my results should only ever have one digit after the decimal so it should be ok! I feel stupid now.

Comment: In mathematics, both odd and even are defined for integers exclusively - so you can't say 2122.6 is odd or even at all. Even itself means that if you divide an integer by 2 it is still an integer.

Comment: Paul perhaps you missunderstand how floats work ... they never have "only one digit" after the decimal.

Comment: Your last digit isn't even undefined, since floats aren't precise. That's the point of @Eric's remark. @cmd solution doesn't work, for example `str(2122.799999999) == '2122.8'` (on my system).

Comment: What about `5/11`? Is that odd or even?

Comment: I think I understand erics 2.60000001 now. I am only ever printing out 1 digit after the decimal, so all that matters is if that digit is a multiple of 2 or not..

Comment: @Paul: Then look at `int(number*10) % 2`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I am only ever printing out 1 digit after the decimal, so all that matters is if that digit is a multiple of 2 or not. [comment by OP]

That simplifies your problem to the point where it is solvable:

```
int(x * 10) % 2 == 0  # even
```

Comment: This is a perfect answer to a non-perfect question.

Comment: @eumiro: In this answer, 1. also prints even. What is the difference with my solution?

Comment: @segfolt - OP commented on this later - he wants to check the first digit after the decimal point, not a random last digit in the string representation of a float. So for `1.`, 'even' is the correct answer.

Comment: @eumiro: I didn't see the comment. What a bad-formulated question! So you were right (for the last digit, before the edit) if the number is a big one.